# Using Java classes from Ruby in an OSGi environment

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I have to run some Ruby scripts using JRuby in an OSGi environment. In these Ruby scripts, I need to use Log4J, so I write something like:

```
require "C:\\path\log4j.jar"
# ....
ois = JRubyObjectInputStream.new(java.io.BufferedInputStream.new(socket.to_inputstream))            
log4j_obj = ois.readObject                      
event["message"] = log4j_obj.getRenderedMessage
# ....
```

It works fine, but now I want to install Log4J in the OSGi environment and use it in the Ruby script. How can I do that?

Comment: Is your main question around what to use for the `require` line, as you can no longer just assume a particular path to the jar file? I assume you meant `jar` instead of `rar`...

Comment: oh,yes .This is my mistake when edit code to post question :).I mean jar not rar

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know much about OSGi, but I would hope that the container would put libraries like Log4J onto the classpath. If that's the case, then you can simply:

```
require 'log4j.jar'
```